# Why doesn't my component fill the whole screen?

Tags: flutter, flame

I'm trying to fill the whole screen with 6 rows and 4 columns of SpriteComponent, but there are always gaps in between, I've checked my code and I don't know what's wrong

[image]

Here is code for FlameGame:

```
List<List<SquareComponent>> grids;

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    await super.onLoad();
    gridWidth = size.x / 4;
    gridHeight = size.y / 6;

    grids = List.generate(
      6,
      (i) => List.generate(
          4,
          (j) => SquareComponent(
              position: Vector2(j * gridWidth, i * gridHeight),
              size: Vector2(gridWidth, gridHeight),
              color: getRandomColor())),
    );

    for (var square in grids) {
      addAll(square);
    }
  }
```

here is SquareComponent:

```
class SquareComponent extends PositionComponent with HasGameRef<MyGame>{
  Color color;
  final Random random = Random();
  late Sprite cardSprite;

  SquareComponent({
    required Vector2 size,
    required Vector2 position,
    required this.color,
  }) : super(size: size, position: position);

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    await super.onLoad();
    cardSprite = await gameRef.loadSprite('img.png');
    add(SpriteComponent(
      sprite: cardSprite,
      position: position,
      size: size,
      anchor: Anchor.topLeft
    ));
  }
}
```

Thanks for the hint!

I simplified the code for just one row, Here is the printed results and screenshot:

```
flutter: position[0.0,155.33333333333334] size[107.5,155.33333333333334]
flutter: position[53.75,155.33333333333334] size[107.5,155.33333333333334]
flutter: position[107.5,155.33333333333334] size[107.5,155.33333333333334]
flutter: position[161.25,155.33333333333334] size[107.5,155.33333333333334]
```

since the screen size is [430.0,932.0], I dont understand why the size is not aligned with the position.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are having is that you are setting the position both on the `SquareComponent` and on the `SpriteComponent` which makes you render half of the sprites outside of the screen, since the `SpriteComponent`'s position is relative to the `SquareComponent` and thus you add double as much to the position as what you intend.

Just remove the `position` (or set it to `Vector.zero()`) on the `SpriteComponent` and it will work:

```dart
    add(
      SpriteComponent(
        sprite: cardSprite,
        size: size,
        anchor: Anchor.topLeft
      ),
    );
```

Comment: hi spydon thank you as always:) that really helps me and now I understander flame better... I tried to ask chatgpt but it seems AI is not as smart as human being yet :)